# Is it frowned upon to prune your own questions and delete inactive ones?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes when I am struggling with a problem, I'll go and make a Stack Overflow question for it, but as soon as I do, I will continue to thoroughly research it with the intent to try to solve it on my own.

While I'm sure that's the kind of practice people prefer, this has sometimes led to me finding my own answers - or discovering that what I want to do isn't a good idea in the first place.

Additionally, sometimes I'll find a problem so insurmountable that I'll just change directions and go a path that doesn't require it to be answered anymore.

In the past, I deleted those of my questions if no real responses had been added, but a colleague of mine said that deleting your own questions reduces your reputation. Is there any truth to this? If so, what is the preferred behavior when a question's lifespan has effectively ended? Should I just leave them open forever? Should I post my own answer?

Comment: It reduces your reputation insofar as you lose any rep from upvotes on it. *"Should I post my own answer?"* - if you have one, of course!

Comment: If they're objectively answerable, it's fine to leave them open. Someone might know a good answer - and help others in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Ironically, what should I do with this question? Can one of you post your response so I may award credit?

Comment: "this has sometimes led to me finding my own answers" [Don't hesitate to answer your own question then.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go over the situations one by one.

> Sometimes when I am struggling with a problem, I'll go and make a stackoverflow question for it, but as soon as I do, I will continue to thoroughly research it with intent to try and solve it on my own.

Great! Don't forget to post the answer you found. It may help someone else in the future.

> While I'm sure that's the kind of practice people prefer, this has sometimes led to me finding my own answers - or discovering that what I want to do isn't a good idea in the first place.

So the answer is "that wasn't a good idea". That is an answer too. However, we have some over-zealous people here, so posting "this was a bad idea" as a self-answer is risky. It's best to give a postive swing - "This turned out to be a bad idea because <....>, this is what I did instead."

> sometimes I'll find a problem so insurmountable that I'll just change directions and go a path that doesn't require it to be answered anymore.

Ok, these are the ones that *might* need deletion. But it's also possible that someone actually knows a good, workable answer. Some approach that you never heard of. For that reason, you might want to leave it - that someone can then post the answer. Even if it's not useful for you anymore, it might still help out others in the future.

> In the past, I would go find these questions I'd ask and delete them if no real responses had been added - but a colleague of mine said that deleting your own questions reduces your reputation. Is there any truth to this?

All reputation from that post will be reset if you delete it if it's less than 60 days old. Since upvotes give more points than downvotes, this is likely to cost some points.

The bigger risk when deleting questions is that it might get you closer to a question ban. The precise algorithm for banning is deliberately kept secret by SE, so we don't know how much a deleted question counts.
You should, however, get a warning if you come near the ban. So don't delete questions too fast, and pay attention to any warnings the system gives you.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is on-topic, just leave it open.  [Self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own questions is perfectly acceptable, and even encouraged.  This can help signal to other users that you have found a solution.  Others who later end up in the same situation now have your answer to help them, and others looking for questions to answer can skip past your question since it already has an answer.  Sometime even alternative solutions can be helpful if you decide to sidestep the original problem.

> but a colleague of mine said that deleting your own questions reduces your reputation. Is there any truth to this?

Deleted posts reset any reputation changes from votes on the post.  So you could lose reputation if your question had upvotes, but you could also gain back reputation lost to downvotes.  In general, deleting upvoted questions is a bad idea not only because you lose reputation but also because others in the community believe that it is a good question.